# How to compile dnsmasq 2.78?

Tags: compiling, dns

I wanted to compile the new dnsmasq from [thekelleys.org](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/dnsmasq-2.78.tar.gz). This worked, but then I realized that the flags are not the same as in the original ubuntu-version 2.76-5:

```
Dnsmasq version 2.76  Copyright (c) 2000-2016 Simon Kelley
Compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP 
DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ipset auth DNSSEC loop-detect inotify

Dnsmasq version 2.78  Copyright (c) 2000-2017 Simon Kelley
Compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt no-DBus no-i18n no-IDN DHCP 
DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP no-conntrack ipset auth no-DNSSEC loop-detect inotify
```

So I changed the config.h but got some errors which I don't know to resolve:

#define HAVE_CONNTRACK:

```
conntrack.c:21:59: fatal error: 
libnetfilter_conntrack/libnetfilter_conntrack.h: No such file or directory
```

#define HAVE_IDN: idna.h not found.

#define HAVE_DNSSEC:

```
dnssec.c:22:24: fatal error: nettle/rsa.h: No such file or directory
```

Where is libnetfilter_conntrack.h and how to include rsa.h?
Where can I find the config.h for the current ubuntu version which has already been modified by canonical?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compile `dnsmasq` on your own you should install development headers for the libraries it links to, plus `gettext` for the internationalization (i18n). On ubuntu, it would be these packages:

- gettext
- libdbus-1-dev
- libidn11-dev
- libnetfilter-conntrack-dev
- nettle-dev

In general, you have a file name such as `libnetfilter_conntrack.h` and you want to know which package provides that file you can use the web site https://packages.ubuntu.com/ and then use 'search for the contents of packages', it will take you to https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libnetfilter_conntrack.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=bionic&arch=any and tell you the package you search for is called `libnetfilter-conntrack-dev`.

So now, if you modify `dnsmasq`s `src/config.h` like this:

```
--- a/src/config.h
+++ b/src/config.h
@@ -175,10 +175,10 @@ RESOLVFILE

 */


 /* #define HAVE_LUASCRIPT */ 
-/* #define HAVE_DBUS */
-/* #define HAVE_IDN */
-/* #define HAVE_CONNTRACK */
-/* #define HAVE_DNSSEC */
+#define HAVE_DBUS
+#define HAVE_IDN
+#define HAVE_CONNTRACK
+#define HAVE_DNSSEC
```

and you use `make all-i18n` as the make target, you'll get a binary with the same options as stock ubuntu:

```
$ make all-i18n

$ src/dnsmasq -v
Dnsmasq version 2.77test4-8-g4e7694d  Copyright (c) 2000-2016 Simon Kelley
Compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP
conntrack ipset auth DNSSEC loop-detect inotify
```

And if you want to find out which options or even patches Ubuntu exactly used to compile their binary package, you can use `apt-get source dnsmasq` to get the sources for the package with the same name.